# Confussion on submersion theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Hi everyone? I was reading "Lectures on Kähler geometry" by Andrei Moroianu, which claims the following:

> If $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a submersion(where $M$ and $N$ are differentiable manifolds) ,then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth submanifold of $M,\forall y\in N$

This result can also be found in the following wikipedia article: 
See here

So my question is: Given $M=N=\mathbb{R}^3$. Clearly, $M$ and $N$ are differentiable manifolds and $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x)=x$ (That is $f=Id$). $f$ is clearly a submersion for $det(df)=det(\mathbb{1})=1>0)$

Then $f^{-1}(x)=\{x\}$. However, $\{x\}$ is not (locally)homemorphic to any open subset of
$\mathbb{R}^n$. For any such set is either empty or uncountable(and $\{x\}$ is none).
Which means $f^{-1}(x)$ can't be a differentiable manifold!

So the question is: What am I getting wrong about this well-accepted theorem? Thanks to everyone!

Edit: It's being pointed out correctly in the comments that $\{x\}$ is a 0-dimensional manifold. However, let's consider $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then, $f^{-1}(1)=\emptyset$. What happens now? How is this a contradiction?

Comment: I believe the correct statement of the theorem is that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth CLOSED submanifold of $M$. Then there is no contradiction, since singleton sets $\{x\}$ are closed subsets.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ have dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively, and if $f : M \to N$ is a smooth submersion, then the preimages are submanifolds of dimension $m-n$. In your situation, $m=n$, hence the preimages have dimension 0. Since $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ is by definition the 0-dimensional vector space $\{0\}$ over the reals, any singleton is diffeomorphic to the open set $\mathbb{R}^0$. It works!

Comment: Submanifolds must be manifolds, right? Also, because $f$ is continous, $f^{-1}(y)$ must be closed, but this changes nothing. Because my concerns are not on whether  $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed but that it should be a manifold

Comment: @JordanPayette Yeah... It's weird but that works. So singletons are manifolds? However, $\emptyset$ is not, and it is possible to build an $f$ so that  $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$. What happens then?

Comment: Yes submanifolds must be manifolds in their own right. But what is an open subset of R^0=point?

Comment: Then it is by definition not a submersion.

Comment: @user587399 How not?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your attention! I've edited the question to include one extra case. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Well i guess it depends on your definition of submersion, but if the preimage is empty, then the submersion condition does not make sense.

Comment: @user587399 The book's definition is that $df$ is surjective on everypoint. With this definition. Isn't the f given in the edit a submersion?

Comment: The wikipedia page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics) and its statement of the result is about the **fibres** of $f$. A fibre of $f$ is a set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ where $y$ is in the range of $f$, so $f^{-1}(1)$ is not a fibre of $f$ in your example.

Comment: Yes, it is. The statement of the theorem should then strictly speaking be altered accordingly, I.e. only where the preimage is no empty. Alternatively you can also consider the empty set as a manifold. This cleans up a lot of statements!

Comment: @user587399  I see, thanks you very much. Btw, If we were to consider $\emptyset$ a diff manifold, what would be it's dimension?

Comment: Having looked around some more, it seems that lots of people disagree with me about the notion of fibre. I think my definition is best: the fibres of $f : X \to Y$ should be the equivalence classes of the relation on $X$ defined by $x_1 \simeq x_2$ if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, but as there is some disagreement about this, the case when the "fibre" $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \emptyset$ probably should be taken care of in the statement of your theorem.

Comment: You are hitting the nail on the head! There would be no good definition of dimension for the empty set as a manifold. At least if you want to have all the usual dimension identities when you take products etc.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree that your definition feels very natural and takes care of the "pathological" $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$ case

Comment: @user587399 I see, this is like $\emptyset$ in projective spaces all over again haha

Comment: As another question, whom should I give the correct answer to? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preimage of a regular value Is a submanifold, so it does not need to be of the same dimension as the ambient manifold. In your example the preimage is a zero dimensional manifold. In general for submersions, the dimension of the preimage of a point is the dimension of the source manifold minus the dimension of the target manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your addition to your question: the correct statement of the submersion lemma is as follows. 
Suppose that $M,N$ are $C^1$ manifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively, and $f: M \to N$ is a submersion. Then for every $x \in M$, there are charts $\phi$ and $\psi$ defined near $x$ and $f(x)$ so that $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is the linear projection on the first $m-n$ coordinates.

As a corollary, the fibers $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for $y \in N$ are either empty or submanifolds of dimension $m-n$.

So yes, good catch, the wikipedia article is a bit unprecise. When your submersion is not surjective, you can indeed have empty fibers, as in your example.

Comment: Great! Btw, do you mean $\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$?

Comment: for me a chart goes from the manifold to $\mathbb R^n$. it's getting late so I might mess up, but with this convention I think it's what I wrote

Comment: Ah, then it's fine